# javascript winow.find() how to begin search from the top every time I hit search button

Tags: javascript, search, find

I am implementing safari browser search kind of functionality.

```
function findSearchResults(searchString, direction)
{
    if (direction == SEARCH_PREVIOUS)
    {
        backwards = true;
    }

    if (window.find(searchString, false, backwards, true))
    {
       //word highlight code
    }
}
```

It is working as I wanted. The only thing I couldn't figure out is, When I am in the middle of document lets say 5 of 10 results, and search for another string, its not performing search from the top of the page instead it is searching from the position where it was in previous search in the document. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search begins from the current selection, if you want to start the search from the top of the page each time, you need to set the current selection appropriately.

```
window.getSelection().empty()
```

This should reset the selection and start the search from the top

http://help.dottoro.com/ljkjvqqo.php